Creating a pseudorandom matrix with a specific determinant and specific entropy
I was sampling several markov matrices for a project, for that:
I want to create a random matrix, which

is markovian(simply it's rows sum to one) and all its elements are between 0 and 1
it has a specific determinant(let's say d)
has a specific entropy(lets say e)
Initially, I created matrices by initializing a random matrix, summing rows, and dividing each element by the sum to ensure a valid Markov property (row sums equal 1). However, I now face these additional constraints

Entropy for a markovian matrix is calculated as
if you have P the markovian matrix and its normalised eigenvector mu with eigen value 1

While I haven't grasped analytical methods for finding entropy, I've explored some approaches for the determinant. These include scaling the matrix, dividing it by a suitable factor such that its determinant changes but that doesn't seem to preserve the markov property, in case I normalise the rows again, the determinant changes too, because we are dividing the rows by a non zero constant. The other approach was expanding the equation for the determinant in terms of its elements which gives me an equation in n variables. I generate n-1 variables randomly and determine the nth variable taking a specific value of the determinant, again the problem that arises with this method is that all the other rows remain normalised except the row having the nth variable.
I have tried to tackle this stochastically for now, having a tolerance level for these properties and selecting the matrix whose properties lie between these. But the time complexity for this method would blow up for higher dimensions.
I'd greatly appreciate any insights into analytical methods to achieve these results or ways to modify existing matrices to meet the constraints.
